# If statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, database-connection

Look at lines #111 and #116

```
<?php
class Connection_model extends CI_Model {
    private $validated;
    private $sender_db;
    private $sender_host;
    private $sender_user;
    private $sender_pw;
    private $receiver_db;
    private $receiver_host;
    private $receiver_user;
    private $receiver_pw;
    public $err_sender;
    public $err_receiver;


    private function define_database($target) {
        if (in_array('sender', $target)) {
            $db['sender'] = array(
                    'dsn'   => '',
                    'hostname' => $this->sender_host,
                    'username' => $this->sender_user,
                    'password' => $this->sender_pw,
                    'database' => $this->sender_db,
                    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
                    'dbprefix' => '',
                    'pconnect' => FALSE,
                    'db_debug' => TRUE,
                    'cache_on' => FALSE,
                    'cachedir' => '',
                    'char_set' => 'utf8',
                    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                    'swap_pre' => '',
                    'autoinit' => TRUE,
                    'encrypt' => FALSE,
                    'compress' => FALSE,
                    'stricton' => FALSE,
                    'failover' => array(),
                    'save_queries' => TRUE
            );
            return $db['sender'];
        }
        elseif (in_array('receiver', $target)) {
            $db['receiver'] = array(
                    'dsn'   => '',
                    'hostname' => $this->receiver_host,
                    'username' => $this->receiver_user,
                    'password' => $this->receiver_pw,
                    'database' => $this->receiver_db,
                    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
                    'dbprefix' => '',
                    'pconnect' => FALSE,
                    'db_debug' => TRUE,
                    'cache_on' => FALSE,
                    'cachedir' => '',
                    'char_set' => 'utf8',
                    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                    'swap_pre' => '',
                    'autoinit' => TRUE,
                    'encrypt' => FALSE,
                    'compress' => FALSE,
                    'stricton' => FALSE,
                    'failover' => array(),
                    'save_queries' => TRUE
            );
            return $db['receiver'];
        }
    }


    // Validate the connection(s)
    private function validate($target) {
        /* @param: Can be 'sender' (string), 'receiver' (string) or 'sender' and 'receiver' (array) */ 
        // Go through all parameters and define an array            
        if ($target == 'sender' || in_array('sender', $target)) {
            $sessions = array('connection', 'sender_db', 'sender_host', 'sender_user', 'sender_pw');
        }
        elseif ($target == 'receiver' || in_array('receiver', $target)) {
            $sessions = array('connection', 'receiver_db', 'receiver_host', 'receiver_user', 'receiver_pw');
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error: illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.';
        }

        // Check if all keys from the array are saved in session
        if (isset($sessions)) : 
            foreach ($sessions as $value) {
                if (key_exists($value, $this->session->get_userdata())) {                   
                    $this->validated = true;
                }
            }   
        endif;                  
    }


    // Establish one or many connections
    /* @param: Can be 'sender' (string), 'receiver' (string) or 'sender' and 'receiver' (array) */
    public function establish($target) {
        if ($target == 'receiver' || in_array('receiver', $target)) { $receiver = 1; }
        elseif ($target == 'sender'  || in_array('sender', $target)) { $sender = 1; }
        if ($sender = 1 || $receiver == 1) {    
            $db_values = array();   
            $this->validate($target);
            if ($this->validated) {         
                // Aight, let's go ahead and connect this baby              
                if ($sender == 1) {
                    array_push($db_values, 'sender');
                    $this->sender_db = $this->session->userdata('sender_db');
                    $this->sender_host = $this->session->userdata('sender_host');
                    $this->sender_user = $this->session->userdata('sender_user');
                    $this->sender_pw = $this->session->userdata('sender_pw');                   
                    if ($this->load->database($this->define_database($db_values))) {
                        $this->err_sender = 0;
                        return $this->load->database($this->define_database($db_values), TRUE);
                    }   
                    else {
                        echo '<br>AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH<br>';
                        $this->err_sender = 1;
                        $this->session->unset_userdata('connection');
                    }
                }
                elseif ($receiver == 1) {
                    array_push($db_values, 'receiver');
                    $this->receiver_db = $this->session->userdata('receiver_db');
                    $this->receiver_host = $this->session->userdata('receiver_host');
                    $this->receiver_user = $this->session->userdata('receiver_user');
                    $this->receiver_pw = $this->session->userdata('receiver_pw');
                    if ($this->load->database($this->define_database($db_values))) {                        
                        $this->err_receiver = 0;
                        return $this->load->database($this->define_database($db_values), TRUE);                     
                    }
                    else {                      
                        $this->err_receiver = 1;
                        $this->session->unset_userdata('connection');
                    }                                           
                }   
                else {
                    echo 'Error: illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.';
                }   
                if ($this->err_receiver == 1 || $this->err_sender == 1) {                   
                    // redirect('home');
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Oops, there is an error! For some reason the property "validated" is not returning true (Connection_model.php)';
                exit;
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error: illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.';
        }
    }

}
```

I ALWAYS get the `echo 'AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH'`. This is probably because `if ($this->load->database($this->define_database($db_values)))` returns `false`. But why does it return `false`? It should only return `false` when the database connection could not be established.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see, is in your method `establish()`, you have a syntax error in your if conditional, as you may already know `=` assigns what the variable means, and `==` compares two variables. Change the following:

you have:

```
 if ($sender = 1 || $receiver == 1) {
```

it should be :

```
 if ($sender == 1 || $receiver == 1) {
```

---

Second problem I see, when you check for the keys in session. According to your comment, you're iterating through the sessions array to check if **ALL** keys are saved, if one is set then it will set to true, then check the next, but what if one is not set youre not setting it to false. Fix it like this:

```
if (isset($sessions)):
    foreach ($sessions as $value) {
        if (key_exists($value, $this->session->get_userdata())) {
            $this->validated = true;
        } else {
            $this->validated = false;
            break;
        }
    }
endif;
```

---

Third problem, when you're checking if your database has loaded, your if statement is not checking for a bool therefore always giving you the same result. To receive a bool, you have to first change your database `db_debug` to `FALSE`, then try to `initialiaze` the db and check for results like this:

```
private function define_database($target) {
    if (in_array('sender', $target)) {
        $db['sender'] = array(
            'dsn' => '',
            'hostname' => $this->sender_host,
            'username' => $this->sender_user,
            'password' => $this->sender_pw,
            'database' => $this->sender_db,
            'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
            'dbprefix' => '',
            'pconnect' => FALSE,
            'db_debug' => FALSE, //SET THIS TO FALSE
            'cache_on' => FALSE,
            'cachedir' => '',
            'char_set' => 'utf8',
            'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
            'swap_pre' => '',
            'autoinit' => TRUE,
            'encrypt' => FALSE,
            'compress' => FALSE,
            'stricton' => FALSE,
            'failover' => array(),
            'save_queries' => TRUE,
        );
        return $db['sender'];
    } //....your other code
}
```

Now in `establish()`:

```
$db_obj = $this->load->database($this->define_database($db_values));
if ($db_obj->initialize()) {
    $this->err_sender = 0;
    return $db_obj;
} else {
    echo '<br>AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH<br>';
    $this->err_sender = 1;
    $this->session->unset_userdata('connection');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used your code but I get the following error: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object ... `var_dump($db_obj->initialize());` returns just nothing?!

Comment: in `applications\config\autoload.php`, im assuming you already have `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` correct?

Comment: No, I don't get any other errors so far. And yes, my $autoload looks the same as you mentioned.

Comment: man.. do you want me to help you remotely? maybe through Teamviewer?

Comment: Sure, I appreciate that. My mic is not working at the time but at least you could take a look at my whole code if you like. Maybe you find something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71925/discussion-between-codegodie-and-sub-zero).

Answer (score -1):

change this line

```
if ($sender = 1 || $receiver == 1) {
```

to this line

```
if ($sender == 1 || $receiver == 1) {
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, will try to follow rules in future given here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer